# regex extract in google data studio

Tags: regex, looker-studio

I am trying to extract values (in this case max and min price ) from page google analytics dimension but having a problem since the position for the max/min price can vary depending on the search that the user took.

I tried : `REGEXP_EXTRACT(Page,'.*minPrice.=(.*)')`

It works fine when the value is at end of the string but catches the rest of the string when the value is at the beginning or in the middle.

[image: output]

Here is an example of page values:

/search/detail/119441465?s[propertyTypes][0]=house&s[propertyTypes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkhUw.png)=condo&s[minPrice]=999999&s[locations][0][city]=Ocean City&s[locations][0][state]=NJ

/search?s[propertyTypes][0]=house&s[propertyTypes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkhUw.png)=condo&s[minPrice]=999000&s[orderBy][0]=r&s[locations][0][city]=Barnegat Light&s[locations][0][state]=NJ

/search/detail/118588431?s[propertyTypes][0]=house&s[propertyTypes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkhUw.png)=condo&s[minPrice]=999000&s[locations][0][city]=Barnegat Light&s[locations][0][state]=NJ

/search/detail/118588431?s[city]=Barnegat Light&s[state]=NJ&s[propertyTypes][0]=house&s[propertyTypes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkhUw.png)=condo&s[minPrice]=999000

/search/detail/119438690?s[orderBy]=sourceCreationDate,desc&s[locations][0][city]=Venice&s[locations][0][state]=FL&s[maxPrice]=525000&s[minPrice]=99900

/search?s[orderBy]=sourceCreationDate,desc&s[locations][0][city]=Venice&s[locations][0][state]=FL&s[maxPrice]=525000&s[minPrice]=99900

/search/detail/119337213?s[orderBy]=sourceCreationDate,desc&s[locations][0][state]=NJ&s[locations][0][county]=Monmouth County&s[maxPrice]=1488000&s[minPrice]=992000

/search/detail/119415983?s[orderBy]=sourceCreationDate,desc&s[locations][0][state]=NJ&s[locations][0][county]=Monmouth County&s[maxPrice]=1488000&s[minPrice]=992000

/search/detail/119046654?s[orderBy]=sourceCreationDate,desc&s[locations][0][state]=NJ&s[locations][0][county]=Gloucester County&s[maxPrice]=148800&s[minPrice]=99200

/search?s[orderBy]=sourceCreationDate,desc&s[locations][0][state]=NJ&s[locations][0][county]=Gloucester County&s[maxPrice]=148800&s[minPrice]=99200

/search/detail/119330920?s[orderBy]=sourceCreationDate,desc&s[locations][0][state]=NJ&s[locations][0][county]=Gloucester County&s[maxPrice]=148800&s[minPrice]=99200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```sql
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Page,'[[]minPrice[]]=([0-9]+)')
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Page,r'\[minPrice]=(\d+)')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sX4mOd/1). *Details*:

- `[[]minPrice[]]=` / `\[minPrice]=` - `[minPrice]=` string
- `([0-9]+)` / `\d+` - Group 1: one or more digits.

The `.*` is not necessary as the `REGEXP_EXTRACT` does not anchor the matches at the start of string.

Comment: Done. One more question if not a problem. How about picking up value under location 0:
[locations][0][city]=VALUE&s

Comment: @user3191724 I think it will be `r'\[locations]\[0]\[city]=([^&?#]+)'`, see [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sX4mOd/3).

Comment: One more question. I'm trying to extract property type when [propertyTypes] can have [0] or [] : 
/search/detail/119441465?s[propertyTypes][0]=house&spropertyTypes=condo&s[minPrice]=999999&s[locations][0][city]=Ocean City&s[locations][0][state]=NJ
/search?s[locations][0][city]=Newark&s[locations][0][state]=NJ&s[propertyTypes][]=house&pvl=1&lvl=1&hvl=1&photoCountMin=1&r=1&noEdit=1&limit=8

Comment: @user3191724 To match an optional `0` char use `0?`.

Comment: This field can have 2 versions for extraction (mutually exclusive): 
[propertyTypes][]= or  [propertyTypes][0]=  

[propertyTypes][1]= , [propertyTypes][2]= etc will go separate fields.

Comment: @user3191724 Sorry, I don't get you. See https://regex101.com/r/sX4mOd/4 and https://regex101.com/r/sX4mOd/5.

Comment: No worries "0?" worked perfectly! Thank you my friend !